# Is it wrong to use a master-detail on smartphone (mobile) with two scrolls?

Tags: mobile, master-details

I'm wondering whether two scrollable areas which resides one next to the other is a good design?
You can see in the following picture.

For the sake of argument let say that the location of item 1 is the connection point between the master and the detail.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvAVpF.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Oh no, don't do this. You don't have enough screen real estate in portraitmode. If you have more room it might be okay, but it depends on the pixel density and the viewport of the device. For small smartphones it's just simply too narrow. You'll have a huge chance of unintentional scrolling which is really a bad experience. Besides, how long are the labels going to be? If they are more than a few characters, they won't even fit in the reserved space

Is it really necessary to display them both? Is it not possible to use a hamburger navigation (the correct term is sidebar navigation, but I like hamburger more :) ). See Facebook, Google+ or Mashable for example

Comment: +1 For unintentional scrolling.  It isn't just a problem of appearance; scrolling using a very narrow band is more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a wrong design. As far as mobile is concerned, having two scrollable sections is not convenient at all. Mostly the width of a handheld device is around 320 pixel, which is too small to be divided into two sections.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is not a good idea. The iphone 5 has a width of 320px. Not only is the screen real estate too small, but I have no idea how you can incorporate links on the left column that would be legible enough to read.

If all smartphones were the size of Galaxy Note, that's a different story.